# Compiling python 3.7 on Solaris 11.2 fails at link stage

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, linker-errors, solaris

I am trying to compile python 3.7 on solaris 11.2. The compiling seems to be error free until the linking phase.  I do not have root access.

I have tried the following:

```
  ./configure --prefix=/appgroup/appuser
  make

  ./configure --prefix=/appgroup/appuser --enable-shared
  make
```

Both error out with:

```
gcc    -o python Programs/python.o -Wl,-R,/appgroup/appuser/scripts/lib -L. -lpython3.7m -lsocket -lnsl -lintl -ldl -lsendfile   -lm  
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
libintl_bind_textdomain_codeset     ./libpython3.7m.so
libintl_gettext                     ./libpython3.7m.so
libintl_textdomain                  ./libpython3.7m.so
libintl_dcgettext                   ./libpython3.7m.so
libintl_bindtextdomain              ./libpython3.7m.so
libintl_dgettext                    ./libpython3.7m.so
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `python'
```

I think the error is based on the conflict between /usr/include/libintl.h and /usr/local/include/libintl.h, because the one in /usr/local/include had those variables, while /usr/include does not.

I tried to set CFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include" and CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include", but the result was the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Q: Are you linking with 'libintl`? Have you installed gettext?

Comment: I did not, but it is installed.

Comment: The "unresolveds" are all from libintl.  Soooo ... you need to find yourself a "good" version of libintl and you need to make sure your "build" command uses it.  Since you're on Solaris, I'm not sure how best to accomplish this.  SUGGESTION: `find / -name "libintl*" -print 2>/dev/null`.  Hopefully, you've got at least one library available, and you can just choose the "best" one.

Comment: I found several libintl.  I added -L/usr/local/lib and it linked, making a python executable.  That executable crashes with:   
ld.so.1: python: fatal: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed

Comment: It sounds like you've (finally!  After linking in libintl) successfully built libpython3.7m.so.  But your executable isn't finding it.  SUGGESTION: can you try `make install`?

Comment: make install ends with ld.so.1: python: fatal: libintl.so.8: open failed: No such file or directory. *** Signal 9

Comment: OK: see if you need to run `crle`: http://bwachter.lart.info/solaris/solfaq.html.  EXAMPLE: `crle -l /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib`.  SUGGESTION: Once you get everything working, add your own "response" explaining what you needed to do to get the Python3 build to work for you on Solaris, and "accept" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working.  Thank you paulsm4.

```
make clean
./configure --prefix=/apps/myapp/scripts CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include" 
cp pyconfig.h pyconfig.h-1018-1200
vim +/INTL pyconfig.h                                    

diff pyconfig.h pyconfig.h-1018-1200
    568c568
    < /* #undef HAVE_LIBINTL_H  */
    ---
    > #define HAVE_LIBINTL_H 1
    1463c1463
    < /* #undef WITH_LIBINTL */ 
    ---
    > #define WITH_LIBINTL 1

make 
make test 
... stopped test with Ctrl-C 
... (this machine is in a production environment without internet access)

make install  
python3 -V
    Python 3.7.0
```

There are a couple of issues still, but it does load.